# Change javascript change function to work with page load as well

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using the following code on a form select field to disable a text box when you choose an option

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Automatic').change(function(){
$('#InstallDate').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "TBD");
});
});
```

It works fine if you choose this option from the select menu, but this form is an edit page of an existing entry, so we're pulling whatever value they selected before from MySQL.

So how can I convert this to also do on load if the default value will be TBD?

Comment: $('#Automatic').change(function(){...}).trigger("change")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways.  You could perhaps trigger the change event manually:

```
$('#Automatic').change(function(){
    $('#InstallDate').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "TBD");
}).trigger('change');
```

Or perhaps define and execute the function separately:

```
let automaticChange = function(){
    $('#InstallDate').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == "TBD");
};
automaticChange();
$('#Automatic').change(automaticChange);
```